# SearchDisplayController TableView Segue Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, segue, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I am trying to put a searchDisplayController into my tableviewController. It seems to work very well, but when I click on the tableViewCell and try to segue to the detailViewController, the app crashes.

It only crashes if I am not trying to perform a search. If I click on one of the filtered results, it segues me to the detailViewController just fine. Any ideas on why this might not be working? Thank you!

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath 
*)indexPath {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showBusinessDetails" sender:indexPath];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showBusinessDetails"]) {
        ProfileViewController *destination = [segue destinationViewController];
        NSIndexPath * indexPath = (NSIndexPath*)sender;

        if (self.tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
            destination.title = [[businesses objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] 
            valueForKey:@"name"];
            destination.businessDetails = [businesses objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        }
        else {
            destination.title = [[filteredBusinesses objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] 
            valueForKey:@"name"];
            destination.businessDetails = [filteredBusinesses 
            objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you adding the `UISearchDisplayController` programmatically or using a storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have your if statement backwards. If the table view is the searchResultsTableView, you should be getting businessDetails from filteredBusinesses (not businesses), should you not?

Comment: Thanks, you're right, but it actually appears that my code is not differentiating whether or not the search bar has content. The if statement returns false every time.

Answer (score 0):

You should be asking a similar question about which is the currently active table view in your `UITableViewController` delegate method, `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`.

As you have written it, this delegate method is only capable of responding to `self.tableView`, however you are also expecting it to respond to `self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView`.

To enable it to respond to `self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView`, you should include code similar to this...

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        UIViewController *destinationVC = nil;
        SegueList *segueToList = nil;

        NSString *mainStoryboard = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"UIMainStoryboardFile"];
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:mainStoryboard bundle:nil];

        if ([self.entity isEqualToString:self.localisedEntityDocument]) {
            destinationVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"id_ViewControllerExample1"]; //insert appropriate "ID"
            segueToList = [[SegueList alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"segueView"
                                                         source:self
                                                    destination:destinationVC];

        } else if ([self.entity isEqualToString:self.localisedEntityTransmittal]) {
            destinationVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"id_ViewControllerExample2"]; //insert appropriate "ID"
            segueToList = [[SegueList alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"segueView"
                                                         source:self
                                                    destination:destinationVC];

        } else {
            //error logging
        }
        UITableViewCell *cellSegue = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [self prepareForSegue:segueToList sender:cellSegue];
        [segueToList perform];
    } else {
        //Probably nothing here if you are using a storyboard segues.
    }
}
```

Note above, that you will be required to enter (or apply) a view controller ID to the target view controller in your storyboard.

You will also be required to write a custom segue. I prefer to place mine at the top of the TVC class for which they are required, using code similar to this...

```
#pragma mark - CUSTOM SEGUE
#pragma mark

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/// Subclass of UIStoryboardSegue must override -perform ///
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
@interface SegueList : UIStoryboardSegue

@end

@implementation SegueList

- (void)perform {
    DD_TVC_List *sourceViewController = self.sourceViewController;
    [sourceViewController.navigationController pushViewController:self.destinationViewController animated:YES];
}

@end
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///         END of subclass of UIStoryboardSegue         ///
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

@interface //normal TVC implementation file
```

And finally, include the appropriate code in your TVC `prepareForSegue` method to respond to the segue identifier (in my example code `segueView`) in your delegate method, `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`.